# How to modify Cassandra config values when using helm chart in Terraform

Tags: cassandra, terraform, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I'm using a [Bitnami Helm Chart for Cassandra](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/cassandra) in order to deploy it with Terraform. I'm freshly new to it all, and I struggle with changing one config value, mainly `commitlog_segment_size_in_mb`. I want to do it before I run terraform commands, but in the Helm Chart itself, I failed to find any mentions of it.

I know I can change it after the terraform deployment in the `cassandra.yaml` file, but I would like to have this value controllable, so that another terraform update will not overwrite this file.

What would be the best approach to change values of Cassandra config?

1. Can I modify it in Terraform if it's not in the Helm Chart?
2. Can I export parts of the configuration to a different file, so that I know my next Terraform installations will not overwrite them?

Comment: You should be able to pass a ConfigMap or Secret with cql script that set this properties via `initDBConfigMap` or `initDBSecret`. Create a ConfigMap/Secret with your configuration and pass its name thorough the mentioned field.
Ref: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/1ffa417d8eea252bbb0887f68b5b7a4cd79ffd53/bitnami/cassandra/values.yaml#L280

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to your question but in case you weren't aware of it already, [K8ssandra.io](https://k8ssandra.io/) is a ready-made platform for running Apache Cassandra in Kubernetes using Helm charts to deploy Cassandra with the [DataStax Cassandra Operator](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cass-operator/doc/cass-operator/cassOperatorTOC.html) (cass-operator) under the hood with all the tools built-in:

- [Reaper](http://cassandra-reaper.io/docs/) for automated repairs
- [Medusa](https://github.com/thelastpickle/cassandra-medusa/wiki) for backups and restores
- [Metrics Collector](https://github.com/datastax/metric-collector-for-apache-cassandra) for monitoring with Prometheus + Grafana
- Traefik templates for k8s cluster ingress
- [Stargate.io](https://stargate.io/) - a data gateway for connecting to Cassandra using REST API, GraphQL API and JSON/Doc API

K8ssandra and all components are fully open-source and free to use, improve and enjoy. Cheers!